# PLS-00103 : Symbole "end-of-file"

Tags: plsql

I'm a beginner on PL/SQL, and i wonder why i've got this message :

ORA-06550: Ligne 56, colonne 1 :
PLS-00103: Symbole "end-of-file" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
<variable attachée> << continue close current delete fetch
lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit
forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
json_object json_array)

My code is :

```
DECLARE
    
   info_                VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   objid_               VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   objversion_          VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   attr_                VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   action_              VARCHAR2(32000) := 'DO';
   company_     VARCHAR2(20):= NULL;
   name_value_      VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   item_above_      VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   structure_id_    VARCHAR2(20):= NULL;
   structure_item_type_ VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
   exist_               NUMBER;
    
--Sélection des sociétés pour copie de la structure
cursor get_company_ is
select COMPANY, OBJID, OBJVERSION 
from ACCOUNTING_STRUCTURE
where company = '000'
and COMPANY not in ('AAA','XXX')
and OBJSTATE = 'Active' 
order by COMPANY; 

--Sélection de la structure MODELE 999 basé sur les dernières ajouts
cursor get_structure_modele_ is
SELECT name_value,item_above,structure_id,structure_item_type--,structure_item_type_db,Description,level_no,sorted_item_above,sorted_name_value,sort_order
FROM accounting_structure_item_disp
WHERE company = 'AAA'
AND structure_id = 'XXXXXX' 
ORDER BY OBJVERSION desc;

BEGIN
    
    ERROR_SYS.Record_General('Custom','FUNCTIONALLOWED: Test en cours !');
    
    --Curseur sociétés
    OPEN get_company_;
    FETCH get_company_ INTO company_,objid_,objversion_;    
    CLOSE get_company_;
    
    -- Mettre la structure comptable 'En cours'
    client_sys.Clear_Attr(attr_);
    Client_sys.Add_To_Attr('COMPANY',company_ , attr_); 
    ACCOUNTING_STRUCTURE_API.RE_OPEN__( info_ , get_company_.objid , get_company_.objversion , attr_ , action_ );
    
    --Curseurs segments modèles
    OPEN get_structure_modele_;     
    FETCH get_structure_modele_ into name_value_,item_above_,structure_id_,structure_item_type_;        
    CLOSE get_structure_modele_;
    
    
    --Contrôle de l'existence du NAME_VALUE dans la structure comptable de la société
    select into exist_ case when exists( 
                    select 1 from accounting_structure_item_disp
                    where company = '0AU'
                    and Structure_id = '222222'
                    and name_value = 'Z9AC'
                      ) then 1 else 0 end       
        from dual;                  
        
                --Ajout de la branche
        if exist_ = 0 then      
                ACCOUNTING_STRUCTURE_ITEM_API.Add_Branch( 
                    company_ ,          --:p0 COMPANY
                    structure_id_ ,     --:p1 CBS
                    item_above_ ,       --:p2 ITEM_ABOVE / SORTED_ITEM_ABOVE (1.1)
                    name_value_ );      --:p3 NAME_VALUE (AVFO)                         
        else EXIT
        END if;     
            
    ACCOUNTING_STRUCTURE_API.ACTIVATE__( info_ , get_company_.objid , get_company_.objversion , attr_ , action_ );
    
    
END;`
```

I think this a "END", but i don't know where.

Think in advance :-)

I try different issue but it's always the same.

Comment: There are a couple of syntax errors at first sight. "SELECT INTO" statement syntax is wrong - it needs to be SELECT <your column> INTO variable. Also, the EXIT statement can only be used inside a loop. you want to use RETURN. I suggest you take a step back and write your procedure block by block. Then compile, test and add code. writing an entire procedure and then compiling it takes a lot longer to debug.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I follow your instruction, so i write with some block. I've compiled it without : 'select 1 
 from accounting_structure_item_disp 
 where company = company_ 
 and Structure_id = structure_id_ 
 and name_value = name_value_;' and it's the same error message

Comment: Please do not post followups as an answer to your own question but update your question with the additional info. I suggest you delete the answer. The issue in the last select is that there is no "INTO" clause. In pl/sql you cannot "SELECT FROM", an "INTO" is needed. However that would throw another error. May I suggest you try out your pl/sql logic on a sample dataset (like emp/dept). That way, when you share code, others can run it and help you.